# Add layer above googlemaps layer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I tried to add my own layer on google maps by code from google maps documentation:

```
extension MapViewController {
func addTiles() {
    // Implement GMSTileURLConstructor
    // Returns a Tile based on the x,y,zoom coordinates, and the requested floor
    let urls = { (x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt) -> NSURL in
        let url = "http://example.pl/ras/\(zoom)/\(x),\(y).v\(1).png";

        return NSURL(string: url)!
    }

    // Create the GMSTileLayer
    let layer = GMSURLTileLayer(URLConstructor: urls)
    layer.tileSize = 512
    layer.map = mapView
}}
```

I got smth like this:

[image]

I don't see terrain which should be under my tile. My tiles are transparent. Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

Update: 
Problem is occurring only on the iOS simulator. It is working on real devices.

Comment: Hey Roman, you should put your update as an answer an mark it as resolved ! Your update helped me to resolve the issue

Comment: Done, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is occurring only on the iOS simulator. It is working on real devices.

Comment: Hi @Roman Barzyczak, can you please explain how to get and set x, y, and zoom to get tiles with this block of code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to pass x,y and zoom. It is a block, so it is called by GMSURLTileLayer

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I saw but I am sticking at point that it calls again and again and no image showing at map. Actually I am trying to get it using bounding box. But still I am not sure I am correct or not. Can you please provide me or suggest me any link for reference. That will be much helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Roman Barzyczak. Now I am able to get image but block is calling multiple times and fetch image on each call and set at each block not in specific bounding box. I don't know why this happens. Please help.

Comment: I have create a ticket at stackoverflow. Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506912/adding-layer-at-google-map-using-gmsurltilelayer-in-swift-4-google-maps-on-ios Please help.

Comment: Hi @Roman Barzyczak, Please check, I have mentioned code in above link. I have already spend to much time to resolve but no success. Still no able to get any resolution and also not getting any reference to handle it. Please help if possible. Thanks in advance.