# iOS Simulators doesnt render layer as real device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, simulator

On my iOS app I use a Google Maps view with a GMSLayer, the transparency renders correctly on a real device but the background is white on Simulator, I can't make the screenshots for the App Store...

[image: On Simulator (iPhone XR)]
[image: On real device]

And this is the code I use :

```
// Implement GMSTileURLConstructor
    // Returns a Tile based on the x,y,zoom coordinates, and the requested floor

    let urls: GMSTileURLConstructor = {(x, y, zoom) in
        let url = "http://wxs.ign.fr/[KEY]/geoportail/wmts?LAYER=TRANSPORTS.DRONES.RESTRICTIONS&FORMAT=image/png&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetTile&STYLE=normal&TILEMATRIXSET=PM&TILEMATRIX=" + String(zoom) + "&TILEROW="+String(y)+"&TILECOL="+String(x)
        return URL(string: url)
    }

    // Create the GMSTileLayer

    let layer = GMSURLTileLayer(urlConstructor: urls)

    layer.zIndex = 0
    layer.map = mapView

class TestTileLayer: GMSSyncTileLayer {
override func tileFor(x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt) -> UIImage {

    let url = URL(string : "http://wxs.ign.fr/[KEY]/geoportail/wmts?LAYER=TRANSPORTS.DRONES.RESTRICTIONS&FORMAT=image/png&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetTile&STYLE=normal&TILEMATRIXSET=PM&TILEMATRIX=" + String(zoom) + "&TILEROW="+String(y)+"&TILECOL="+String(x))

    return UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: url!))!
}
}
```

I'm sure the image given by the URL uses transparency and I tried to manually change the white pixel to transparent but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: You might want to look into marker clustering https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simulator problem only it has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37866387/8192960).

However as @a.munzer suggested some work around you can take a screenshot from a real device and just edit it, shouldn't be that much of a problem.